# JQuery Datepicker - setting default date and giving preference to user input on the calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the following code to set fromDate and toDate such that by default, toDate is today's date and fromDate is a date 7 days ago.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
populateDefaultValues();
    showDatePicker();


});

function populateDefaultValues(){
v var endDateString = $('#toDate').val();
        var splitDate = endDateString.split("/");

        var endDate = new Date(splitDate[2], splitDate[0], splitDate[1]);
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 7);

        $("#fromDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", startDate));

}
function showDatePicker(){
$( "#fromDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeDay: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#toDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
    });
    $( "#toDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeDay: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
    });
}
```

The date range gets displayed as expected. However, if I select some other date range in the fromDate using the calendar, during page load, it again goes back to -7 days. How do I stop this from happening? I want to give preference to user's input in fromDate and toDate but by default, lets say when the page gets loaded for the first time, have only one week of date range selected.

For some reason, if I do not use my code above, it selected a date range of 2 weeks which I want to avoid.

Any pointers.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ? Creating environment for this executable is difficult..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
minDate: "-7D",
maxDate: new Date()

Comment: I only want to set default values. Once user changes dates in the calendar, I do not want to override that.